# How to get last iteration in apex:repeat tag in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, developer

I am trying to get the last iteration record in apex:repeat tag and outputs the last iteration record using visualforce and not using apex. I tried using the first attribute but no luck.
Please help me to get last recent record. Thanks in Advance!

```
  <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Histories}" var="hist" first="">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Student Name: "/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!hist.NewValue}"/>
 </apex:repeat>
```

[image: Student History]

Answer (score 0):

You can use apex:variable to calculate number of records to be skipped.

```
<!--Caluclate number of records to be skipped. -->

<apex:variable var="skip" value="{!-1}"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Histories}" var="hist" >
    <apex:variable var="skip" value="{!skip + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>

<!-- skip first relatedTo.Histories.length - 1 records -->
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Histories}" var="hist" first="{!skip}">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Student Name: "/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!hist.NewValue}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Hi @amitghadage, I tried executing but It skipped all the records. I am unable to output the last iteration record.

Comment: @Sanjana What is the length of relatedTo.Histories & value of skip variable after iteration?

Comment: When we update the Student Name in the UI, we get the old value and the New Value in the Histories. I want the recent changed record and skip the rest. Attached the Screenshot for reference.